# Not taking value in foreign key django shell

Tags: django

i have models.py as follows:

```
class category(models.Model):
    cid=models.IntegerField(unique=True,default=0)
    cname=models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.cid,self.cname

    class Meta:
        db_table="category"

class cateledetails(models.Model):
    cdid=models.IntegerField(unique=True,default=0)
    cid=models.ForeignKey(category,to_field='cid',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    elename=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    imgsrc=models.ImageField(upload_to='elements/',blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.cdid,self.elename

    class Meta:
        db_table="cateledetails"
```

and i have made an entry in shell b=category(cid=1,cname='Animal')
b.save()

next  i try to input an entry into cateledetails table and it gives the following error:

python manage.py shell

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:08:48) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.models import category,cateledetails
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named models
>>> from student.models import category,cateledetails
>>> b=category.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> b.cid
1
>>> q=cateledetails(cdid=1,cid=1,'dog')
  File "<console>", line 1
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
>>> q=cateledetails(cdid=1,cid=1,elename='dog')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 468, in __init__
    setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 627, in __set__
    self.field.rel.to._meta.object_name,
ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "cateledetails.cid" must be a "category" instance.
```

why is this error generating?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a `category` instance, where as, you're passing an integral value to it.

**Solution**:

```
q=cateledetails(cdid = 1, cid = b, elename = 'dog')
```

Ref: [Django Related Objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.create)